# Is PHP DateTime object bugged?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I want to increment Timestamp to generate dates (timestamps being assumed with time=0 hour, 0 minute, 0 second). All worked fine along my loop unless the day of 2016-10-30: Example follows:

```
    $date1=new DateTime;
    $date1->setDate(2016,10,30);
    $date1->setTime(0,0,0);
    $date1_str=$date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $timestamp1=$date1->getTimestamp();
    $timestamp2=$timestamp1+(60*60*24);// create the next day...
    $date2=new DateTime;
    $date2->setTimestamp($timestamp2);
    $date2_str=$date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "date1_str=$date1_str; date2_str=$date2_str<br>";
```

The result I get is the following:
date1_str=2016-10-30 00:00:00; date2_str=2016-10-30 23:00:00

The 24 hours increment of timestamp is seen as a 23 hours increment!!
The remaing of the loop keep locked to time 23:00:00 instead of 00:00:00

Comment: No it isn't "bugged".... on the contrary, it's daylight-savings aware; and you've found one of the (typically) two days of the year that don't have 24 hours

Comment: However, `$timestamp2=$timestamp1+(60*60*24);` suggests that you're assuming that every day of the year has 24 hours

Comment: I just had to mention you can use the methods add and modify on the datetime object instead of what you're doing now. `$date = new DateTime('2016-10-30'); $date->modify('+1 days');` does the same as your code. Not saying shorter is always better, but in this case I think it is

Answer (score 1):

When you play with time, and especially with dates you have to have in mind DST ([Daylight Saving Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2016.html)) for the date you referred `30/10/2016` the time changes for some countries in the world, so you have to take it into consideration when you apply your time local settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use **date_default_timezone_set** in the top of your instructions. you can see more information in : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php.

keep in your mind that you will get varying results dependent on your current timezone. for example  when you use date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); you will get : date1_str=2016-10-30 00:00:00; date2_str=2016-10-31 00:00:00

i hop this can help you